# Turn Gatsby code into traditional HTML/CSS/JS files?

Tags: gatsby

I have a side that an agency developed in Gatsby. I'd like to turn that code into traditional, separate HTML, CSS and JS files that I can use myself. Is this possible?

Comment: Gatsby already outputs these files. Or what do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to continue development on the site you should just use gatsby to do that. When gatsby builds, it generates those html css and js files but they are minified for production and it's not a good idea to be editing those.

If you have access to the repo and just want to put the site online, you can log into netlify and deploy the website from gitlab or github.